# Can I customize all my operating systems that I will install on kvm/qemu with Virt-customize?

Tags: kvm-virtualization, freebsd, qemu, openbsd

For my private cloud provider, I want to create a virtual machine from the operating system iso I want using kvm/qemu (since I was looking for an alternative to cloud-init, I chose to customize it with virtual-customize) but I could not customize freebsd and openbsd images with virtual-customize

Comment: On what operating system?

Comment: Operating System: Ubuntu 20.10
  Kernel: Linux 5.8.0-36-generic
  Architecture: x86-64